# Localization and unused files in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have an XCode project which is a game made with Cocos2dx game engine (C++) and native classes for Facebook etc. I recently started localizing it for a second language and I have two copies of a lot assets in two languages (Images etc.). The implementation in my code for switching between languages is perfectly fine using pre-processor directives and compiler doesn't even see (I assume) the assets in one language when it compiles the other.
However, I was wondering if XCode is going to include all the assets and resources, even the ones that are not used into the final file that I upload to app store? Is there anyway to tell XCode not include them, which is as easy as one on/off switch?

Comment: 1. If the images have text in them move it out and overlay the text in code, that reduces the number of assets and makes it easier to port to an additional language. 2. The language choice should be made at run-time based on the users selected languages choices, not at compile-time. Xcode supports run-time localization.

Comment: 1- Actually the in game texts are mostly provided as Label objects inside the game. But there are some that could not be used via fonts for some reason. 2- Also, for localization at compile time, the thing is we are going to make a version for an alternative app store. That's why we need only one language.